# Do modern OS's use paging and segmentation?

Tags: memory, x86, operating-system, paging, memory-segmentation

I was reading about memory architecture and I got a bit confused with the paging and segmentation. I read that modern OS systems use only paging to manage memory access but looking at a disassembled codes I can see segments like "ds" and "fs". Does it means that the OS (saw that on Windows and Linux) is using both segmentation and paging or is it just mapping all the segments into the same pages (making segments irrelevant) ?

Comment: AFAICT, segments are not optional.  but in simple cases they're just set up to all map to the same linear space, making them irrelevant.

Comment: You should probably tag `x86` if that's the architecture you're referring to.

Answer (score 61):

Ok, based on the book Modern Operating Systems 3rd Edition by Andrew S. Tanenbaum and the materials form Open Security Training (opensecuritytraining.info), i manage to understand the segmentation and paging and the answer for my question is:

1. **Concepts:**

   1.1.**Segmentation:**

   Segmentation is the division of the memory into pieces (sections) called segments. These segments are independents from each other, have variable sizes and may grow as needed.

   1.2. **Virtual Memory:**

   A virtual memory is an abstraction of real memory.  This means that it maps a virtual address (used by programs) into a physical address (used by the hardware). If a program wants to access the memory 2000 (mov eax, 2000), the virtual address (2000) will be converted into the real physical address ( for example 1422) and then the program will access the memory 1422 thinking that he’s accessing the memory 2000. 
   So, if virtual memory is being used by the system, programs no longer access real memory directly, instead, they used the correspondent virtual memory.

   1.3. **Paging:**

   Paging is a virtual memory management scheme. As explained before, it maps a virtual address into a physical address. Paging divides the virtual memory into pieces called “pages” and also divides the physical memory into pieces called “frame pages”. A page can be bound to one or more frame page ( keep in mind that a page can map different frame pages, but just one at the time)
2. **Advantages and Disadvantages**

   2.1. **Segmentation:**

   The main advantage of using segmentation is to divide the memory into different linear address spaces. With this programs can have an address space for his code, other for the stack, another for dynamic variables (heap) etc. The disadvantage for segmentation is the fragmentation of the memory. 
   Consider this example – One portion of the memory is divided into 4 segments sequentially allocated -> `seg1(in use) --- seg2(in use)--- seg3(in use)---seg4(in use)`. Now if we free the memory from seg2, we will have -> `seg1(in use) --- seg2(FREE)--- seg3(in use)---seg4(in use)`. If we want to allocate some data, we can do it by using seg2, but if the size of data is bigger than the size of the seg2, we won’t be able to do so and the space will be wasted and the memory fragmented. Another problem is that some segments could have a larger size and since this segment can’t be “broken” into smaller pieces, it must be fully allocated in memory.

   2.1. **Paging:**

   The main advantages of using paging is to abstract the physical memory, hence, the programs (and programmers) don’t need to bother with memory addresses. You can have two programs that access the (virtual) memory 2000 because it will be mapped into two different physical memories. Also, it’s possible to use the hard disk to ensure that only the necessary pages are allocated into memory.  The main disadvantage is that paging uses only one linear address space. Paging maps virtual memories from 0 to the max addressable value for all programs. Now consider this example - two chunks of memory, “chk1” and “chk2” are next to each other on virtual memory ( chk1 is allocated from address 1000 to 2000 and chk2 uses from 2001 to 3000), if chk1 needs to grow, the OS needs to make room in the memory for the new size of chk1. If that happens again, the OS will have to do the same thing or, if no space can be found, an exception will pop. The routines for managing this kind of operations are very bad for performance, because it this growth and shrink of the memory happens a lot of time.
3. **Segmentation and Paging**

   3.1. **Why combine both?**

   An operational systems can combine both segmentation and paging. Why? Because combining then it’s possible to have the best from both without their disadvantages. So, the memory is divided in many segments and each one of those have one or more pages. When a program tries to access a memory address, first the OS goes to the correspondent segment, there he’ll find the correspondent page, so he goes to the page and there he’ll find the frame page that the program wanted to access. Using this approach, the OS divides the memory into various segments, including segments for the kernel and user programs. These segments have variable sizes and access protection features. To solve the fragmentation and the “big segment” problems, paging is used. With paging a larger segment is broken into several pages and only the necessary pages remains in memory (and more pages could be allocated in memory if needed). So, basically, the Modern OSs have two memory abstractions, where segmentation is more used for “handling the programs” and Paging for “managing the physical memory”.

   3.2. **How it really works?**

   An OS running segmentation and Paging will have the following structures:

   3.2.1. **Segment Selector:**

   This represents an index on the Global/Local Descriptor Table. It contains 3 fields that represent the index on the descriptor table, a bit to identify if that segment is present on Global or Local descriptor table and a privilege level.

   3.2.2. **Segment Register:**

   A CPU register used to store segment selector. Usually ( on a x86 machine) there is at least the register  CS (Code Segment) and DS (Data Segment).

   3.2.3. **Segment descriptors:**

   This structure contains the data regarding a segment, like his base address, size ( in pages or in bytes), the access privilege, the information of if this segment is present on the memory or not, etc. (for all the fields, search for segment descriptors on google)

   3.2.4. **Global/Local Descriptor Table:**

   The table that contains several segment descriptors. So this structure holds all the segment descriptors for the system. If the table is Global, it can hold other things like Local Descriptor Tables descriptors, Task State Segment Descriptors and Call Gate descriptors (I’ll not explain these here, please, google them). If the table is Local, it will only ( as far as I know) holds user related segment descriptors.

   3.3. **How it works?**

   So, to access a memory, first the program needs to access a segment. To do this a segment selector is loaded into a segment register and then a Global or Local Descriptor table (depending of field on the segment selector). This is the reason of the fully memory address be `SEGMENT REGISTER: ADDRESS , like CS:ADDRESS -> 001B:0044BF7A`. Now the OS goes to the G/LDT and (using the index field of the segment selector) finds the segment descriptor of the address trying to access. Then it checks if the segment if present, the protection and if everything is ok it goes to the address stated on the “base field” (of the descriptor) + the address offset . If paging is not enabled, the system goes directly into the real memory, but with paging on the address is treated as a virtual address and it goes to the Page directory. The base address + the offset are called Linear Address and will be interpreted as 3 fields: Directory+Page+offset. So on the Directory page, it will search for the directory entry specified on the “directory” field of the linear address, this entry points to the page table and the field “page” of the linear address is used to find the page, this entry points to a frame page and the offset is used to find the exactly address that the program want to access.

   3.4. **Modern Operational Systems**

   Modern OSes "do not use" segmentation. Its in quotes because they use 4 segments: Kernel Code Segment, Kernel Data Segment, User Code Segment and User Data Segment. What does it means is that all user's processes have the same code and data segments (so the same segment selector). The segments only change when going from user to kernel. 
   So, all the path explained on the section 3.3. occurs, but they use the same segments and, since the page tables are individual per process, a page fault is difficult to happen.

Hope this helps and if there is any mistakes or some more details ( I was I bit generic on some parts) please, feel free to comment and reply.
Thank you guys

**Danilo PC**

Comment: You forgot to flag this as a solution

Answer (score 4):

They only use paging for *memory protection*, while they use segmentation for other purposes (like storing thread-local data).